# Intuition behind proving that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{b_n} = \frac{1}{b}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

[image]

Okay, so I'm having a bit of an issue understanding Rosenlicht's proof that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{b_n} = \frac{1}{b}$$

I've worked out the proof and I have written it down myself, but I'm still having a few issues. It seems that Rosenlicht is trying to make sure that, regardless of his choice for $b_n$, that the denominator is *larger* than the numerator, and is bounded away from zero.

How are we able to accomplish this using Rosenlicht's approach? Could someone just elaborate on this proof a bit more? I understand the latter part in completing proof, it's just the first half I'm having trouble with.

Oh, and sorry for posting the entire picture, as I don't have access to a computer right now and am instead on my phone.

Thanks in advance mates.

Comment: The way I would think about this is that if $x_n \to x$ and $f$ is a continuous function, then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. Restricted to nonzero reals $1/x$ is a continuous function, hence, the claim follows. I'm not sure if you are allowed to use these results, but I think in practice you would.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä Interesting approach. So this would circumvent the entire approach Rosenlicht utilizes?

Comment: @ColeButler You still need to (rigorously) justify the application of the $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ principle to a function that is only partially continuous.  Also, how do you *prove* that $1/x$ is continuous away from $0$?  Very often this follows from some general principle that quotients of (non-zero) continuous functions are continuous, and this is similar to what this passage was trying to prove (note the introductory sentence "To prove the last part, about division").  So appealing to this argument is quite likely to be circular.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the fact that $b_{n} \to b$ as $n \to \infty$ and $b \neq 0$. Since $b \neq 0$ we can choose $\epsilon = |b|/2$ in definition of limit to arrive at a positive integer $m$ such that $$|b_{n} - b| < |b|/2$$ for all $n \geq m$. This means that $|b_{n}| > |b|/2 > 0$ for all $n \geq m$. This is what we mean by saying that *$b_{n}$ is bounded away from $0$.*

Next consider $$\left|\frac{1}{b_{n}} - \frac{1}{b}\right| = \frac{|b_{n} - b|}{|b||b_{n}|}$$ On the RHS the denominator is bounded away from $0$ and clearly denominator is greater than $|b|^{2}/2$ if $n \geq m$. The numerator $|b_{n} - b|$ can be made as small as we please (because $b_{n} \to b$) by choosing any value of $\epsilon$. So you can see that denominator can be definitely made bigger than numerator. However this is not the crucial idea in the proof.

*The crucial idea is that numerator can be made as small as we please whereas denominator is always greater than a fixed bound $|b|^{2}/2$. This will ensure that overall fraction can be made as small as we please*. And this is what is needed to show that $1/b_{n} \to 1/b$.